# How to get checkbox data using python on gae

Tags: python, google-app-engine, checkbox

This is my HTML:

```
<div id='automail'>
    <form action = "/admin/mail" method = "get">
        auto mail when user :<br/><br/>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="automail" value ="signup">signUp</input><br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="automail" value ="login">login</input><br/>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:right">
            <input type="submit" value="save"></input>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

And this is my python handle:

```
class mail(BaseRequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        all=self.request.get('automail')
        if not all:
            self.response.out.write('sss')
            return
        self.response.out.write(all)
```

when I choosee 'signup' and 'login', it only show 'signup'.

So how to get all data from checkbox using python on gae?

**updated:**

it is ok now ,two ways :

1.
`all=self.request.get_all('automail')`

2.
 `all=self.request.get('automail',allow_multiple=True)`

Comment: not valid HTML, there's no closing `input` tag

Comment: Great question post however - well layed out

Comment: Note: allow_multiple is a deprecated param. You would now use:
all=self.request.params.getall('automail')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If multiple arguments have the same name, `self.request.get` returns the first one.

You want [get_all](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_get_all).